# sfml/c++ - Using Vector for Multiple Enemy Class

Tags: c++, class, vector, sfml

I'm trying game development. I tried a sample from a tutorial site like this:

```
int number = 10;

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<enemy> > enemies1;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
    enemies1.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<enemy>(new enemy(sf::Vector2f(100 * i + 1500, 1000), sf::Vector2f(15, 10), sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 0))));
}
    //update
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
            enemies1[i]->update();
        }
    //render
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
            window.draw(enemies1[i]->enemysprite);
        }
```

I'm using vector for creating multi enemies from my enemy class. Everything is ok I can draw 10 enemies on screen and they are moving and such. But if I try to delete an enemy like this:

```
    if (!enemies1.empty())
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
            if (enemies1[i]->rect.getGlobalBounds().intersects(sprite.getGlobalBounds())) 
                enemies1.erase(enemies1.begin() + 1);
        }
    }
```

when the program starts a collision occurs everything is stopping. My question is what's the best way to create multiple enemies because I need to spawn and delete them in my game and I'm still learning.
I don't know whether my implementation correct or not. I wonder what should I do? In this code, I can't erase enemies from this vector.
I appreciate every piece of advice.

Answer (score 3):

This loop:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
    if (enemies1[i]->rect.getGlobalBounds().intersects(sprite.getGlobalBounds())) 
        enemies1.erase(enemies1.begin() + 1);
}
```

is flawed, because when you call `erase`, all the subsequent array entries move down 1, so next time round the loop you access the wrong element.  Also, you run off the end of the array.

Instead, you can use the [erase / remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
enemies.erase (std::remove_if (enemies.begin(), enemies.end(),
    [sprite] (const std::unique_ptr <enemy> &e)
        { return e->rect.getGlobalBounds().intersects(sprite.getGlobalBounds()); }, enemies.end());
```

Comment: Or [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2), if you have C++20

Comment: Thanks for advice and spend your time. I will search that erase-remove idiom now.

Comment: enemies1.erase(std::remove_if(enemies1.begin(), enemies1.end(), [sprite](const std::unique_ptr <items> &e) { return e->rect.getGlobalBounds().intersects(sprite.getGlobalBounds()); }), enemies1.end());
with this code i m getting same error program is stopping

Comment: That could be for a number of reasons.  Did you consider stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6F5F64EB0 in game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000188.
it says that

Comment: Is there something wrong with your `enemy` destructor?  And does `enemy` respect the rule of 3 / 5 / 0?  Please post a [mre].

Comment: i shared below with a picture

Comment: OK, thanks (but next time please post as text).  What you need to do now is learn to use your debugger and get a stack trsce.

Comment: Thanks for your help and spend your time

Comment: i used another code like this
 std::vector <enemy*>  enemies;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {

  enemies.emplace_back (new enemies(sf::Vector2f(100 * i + 800, 500), sf::Vector2f(15, 10), sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 0)));
 }

enemies.erase(std::remove_if(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), [](const auto &itr) {return itr->touch; }), enemies.end());
it works and erasing values
but it doesnt remove last value from array.

Comment: How did you test that?  The erase / remove idiom is known to work.

Comment: i tested on my game. 1,2,3,4 enemies have deleted but when i try to delete 5th enemy game is stopping. i changed just this code and at least some of enemies can be deleted

 std::vector <enemy*>  enemies1;
maybe i have to learn much c++ :) i cant find whats wrong on my code. thanks for your effort

Comment: What you need to do is put together a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  Then people can look at it.  I suggest you do this in a new question - this one is getting rather messy,

Answer (score 0):

[My enemy class is this like on shared picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCYDY.jpg)